Do I need to comply with GDPR for a hobby website that displays information of all visitors?
I am an individual (i.e. not an organisation) with a hobby website that has no commercial interest, no third party affiliations, no social media links, and no third party analytics.
When a user opens the site, their visit is logged. I track timestamp, IP, and some information I obtain using that IP - city, region, country, and internet service provider. A cookie is given to the user with a unique identifier to assist in some deduplication of visits. I do not keep this information secure, in fact the explicit purpose of the site is as a public "guest book". The site publicly displays all of the above information of all past visits in a large table for anyone to see.
I have seen this question, which asks whether web applications as hobby projects need to comply with the GDPR, however I feel that the way I am treating data here is somewhat unique, especially as it relates to third parties.
Do I need to comply with GDPR? If so, how? Is it enough to obtain consent before adding people to the guest book, or do I need to do anything extra about the fact that the information is insecure?

This question is similar to: Is it really possible to use Google Analytics without consent, and if so, why exactly?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@trish Actually, can you please explain why it's similar? My question has nothing to do with analytics

you just skip the 3rd party from Google Analytics -you need explicit consent for any cookie that is not strictly technically necessary, and IP is by definition personal data.

But my site does not use any analytics at all, Google or otherwise. This question is about taking peoples information (currently without consent) and displaying it all publicly

You a) set a cookie. b) process Personal Information (the IP).

What has that got to do with analytics?

You basically ask these questions: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/24386/can-i-count-unique-users-without-a-cookie-warning & https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/63660/is-the-creation-of-a-cookie-with-a-anonymous-id-a-violation-of-gdpr-even-if-its and https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/59567/gdpr-concerning-ip-logging-by-hosting-company-inside-eu

The legal argument is that processing the IP and setting a cookie already is analytics. Not very sophisticated analytics but that is irrelevant. What you describe as doing is processing of personal data and hence requires GDPR compliance.

"some information I obtain using that IP" do you do so on your own server, or do you call an external API? That would add a whole other layer of "problematic".

I'd be extremely wary of some "hobby" site collecting and collating all that information, I'd assume they have the full intent of using that information for nefarious purposes.

Whether or not the site itself has nefarious intent, the act of publishing all of the information gives anyone the ability to do whatever they want with it, with whatever intent they may have anyway.

The GDPR Article 2(2)(c) exemption ("by a natural person in the course of a purely personal or household activity") does not seem to be applicable in the hypothetical circumstances described.
Case law says:

"[A]n activity cannot be regarded as being purely personal or domestic where its purpose is to make the data collected accessible to an unrestricted number of people or where that activity extends,even partially, to a public space and is accordingly directed outwards from the private setting of the person processing the data in that manner [...]".  (CJEU - C-25/17 - Jehovan todistajat, margin number 42 with further references.)


"That exception [for the processing of data carried out by a natural person in the exercise of activities which are exclusively personal or domestic] must therefore be interpreted as relating only to activities which are carried out in the course of private or family life of individuals, which is clearly not the case with the processing of personal data consisting in publication on the internet so that those data are made accessible to an indefinite number of people." (CJEU - C-101/01 - Lindqvist, margin number 47)

Via gdprhub.eu.
Therefore this hypothetical website must have a 'lawful basis' (Article 6) for the processing of the personal data.
As for cookies or other storage on the visitor's device, the website must obtain consent from the visitor to set cookies that are not 'strictly necessary' for the website to work (ePrivacy Directive).

This need not be terribly onerous or difficult to comply with. Consent is a lawful basis, and while there are complications in cases where you offer some good or service in exchange for consent, that is not what OP is proposing to do. They already need consent for the cookies anyway, so they may as well ask for data processing consent at the same time. As long as it's reasonably clear what the user is being asked to consent to, I find it hard to believe that the EU would have a problem with that setup.

One could make the argument that the cookie is essential for the purpose of the site (which consists solely in reflecting unique visits).
